# How to disable file thumbnails?

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno

For example, there is a .doc file in Files app and I can see what is in it. But I want to see just .doc template icon.
I'm using Juno.

Comment: You can this solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/523177 Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking for all file types, not just some specific types.

Answer (score 0):

There is a org/gnome/desktop/thumbnailers/disable-all setting but at the moment Files does not appear to honor it.  I would raise an issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues about this.   You might point at that other filemanagers (e.g. Nemo) do have a setting do disable local thumbnails.  Files only has a setting to disable remote thumbnails.

Comment: Looks like there is no way then.

Comment: Not at the moment, but I think this is a bug that would want to be fixed by elementary in the near future.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna create a report at github then. But I don't think this is a bug. I think this is a lack of the future.

Answer (score 0):

Pantheon-files uses a thumbnailer daemon called tumbler. You can disable the generation of thumbnails for PDF, Photos, Documents, etc. by editing the config file.

Open Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc
```

here you have to change `Disabled=false` to `Disabled=true` in the desired section

Ctrl+O, Enter, Ctrl+X to exit nano

Comment: does this works? look like the answer for now